# Setting up Graphhopper (open source version)

Tags: graphhopper

I am looking for an alternative to the Google Directions API and run into Graphhopper, as I need to get matrices that provide the distances and travel times between a group of points given by coordinates.

I have installed the Graphhopper server in Java following [these instructions](https://www.graphhopper.com/blog/2018/09/25/getting-started-with-graphhopper-0-11-and-jdk-11/), and it seems to be running fine.

As I need to send the requests using Python, I also installed the Python client as shown [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-clients/tree/master/python#installation--usage). However, it asks for an API key and refers me to the Graphhopper website to get one.

How can I get the client to make a call to the machine where I have installed the server, instead of trying to reach the Graphhopper API? Is this possible? I have been going through the client files but haven't found any place to enter this information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For anybody in my same situation, I have found an answer. The Matrix API is not open source, so you need to get an API key regardless. Then, you can use the client code (like the one I linked to above) to send queries. The chart of features that are available via the open source code can be found [here](https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/).

I hope that helps!